# How to rewrite all the boolean operations using if-then-else operator?

Tags: logic, computer-science, boolean-algebra

Cited by [Conditional Term Rewriting Systems: 1st International Workshop Orsay, France, July 8-10, 1987, p. 105](https://books.google.com.ua/books?id=TdePXxc1nBEC&pg=RA1-PA105#v=onepage&q&f=false)

> Additional Boolean operations are not needed, because all the usual Boolean operations can be expressed as derived operations in terms of the if-then-else.

This is also mentioned in  Functional Programming Principles in Scala course on Coursera.org by Martin Odersky ([compendium](https://github.com/iirvine/functional-programming-in-scala/blob/master/notes/week%204/002-objects-everywhere.md)):

> Turns out that all the operations on booleans can be defined in terms
>   of ifThenElse.

I guess that could be obvious for those who is familiar with the topic, but how do we know this is possible? How to formulate general rules for performing these operations?

Comment: Please give a concrete example of what you are trying to ask.

Comment: @barakmanos First, I need a proof that all boolean operations can be defined using if-then-else operator. Second, I would like to know what exactly should one do to make such definitions for different boolean operations if possible (how to formulate rewrite rules). You cold refer links at the OP for concrete examples. Look at `def && (x: => Boolean): Boolean = ifThenElse(x, False)`, for instance. This is the definition of logical conjunction rewritten in terms of if-then-else operator using Scala. How to rewrite other boolean operations?

Comment: [Binary decision diagrams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_decision_diagram) are an interesting application of the functional completeness of if-then-else + $\{\top, \perp\}$ with applications in automated reasoning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's try it:

```
AND(x, y) = ITE(x, y, x)
OR(x, y) = ITE(x, x, y)
NOT(x) = ITE(x, false, true)
EXOR(x, y) = ITE(x, ITE(y, false, true), y)
EXNOR(x, y) = ITE(x, y, ITE(y, false, true))
IMPLIES(x, y) = ITE(x, y, true)
NAND(x, y) = ITE(x, ITE(y, false, true), false)
NOR(x, y) = ITE(x, false, ITE(y, false, true))
```

`IfThenElse (ITE)` is not [functionally complete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_completeness), because constants `true` and `false` are required to implement certain functions.